# Selection Sorting a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, selection-sort

For an assignment in my Data Structures class, I was given a node for a linked list containing integers. I keep getting a null pointer exception, but I have been staring at it for too long, and I can't find where I messed up.

---

Here is my sorting class:

```
public class Sorter {

public Sorter() {

}

/*****
 * Sorter
 * takes a linked list, sorts it
 * @param head linked list to sort
 * @return sorted linked list
 */
public IntNode nodeSort(IntNode head) {
    IntNode holderHead = new IntNode(-1, null);
    IntNode cursor;
    int currentMax = -1;
    int count = 0;

    while (count < head.listLength(head)) {
        IntNode tempHead = new IntNode(-1, null);
        for (cursor = head.getLink(); cursor.getLink() != null; cursor = cursor.getLink()) {
            if (currentMax > cursor.getLink().getData()) {
                tempHead.setLink(cursor.getLink());
            }
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            holderHead.setLink(tempHead.getLink());
        } else {
            tempHead.getLink().setLink(holderHead);
            holderHead.setLink(null);
            holderHead = tempHead.getLink();
        }
        count+=1;
    }

    return holderHead;
}
```

---

Here is the IntNode class(Given by my Instructor):

```
public class IntNode {
   private int data;
   private IntNode link;   


   public IntNode(int initialData, IntNode initialLink) {
      data = initialData;
      link = initialLink;
   }


   public void addAfter(int item) {
      link = new IntNode(item, link);
   }          


  public int getData( ) {
      return data;
   }


   public IntNode getLink( ) {
      return link;                                               
   } 


   public static IntNode listCopy(IntNode source) {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;

      if (source == null)
         return null;

      copyHead = new IntNode(source.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;

      while (source.link != null)
      {
         source = source.link;
         copyTail.addAfter(source.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      return copyHead;
   }


   public static IntNode[ ] listCopyWithTail(IntNode source) {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;
      IntNode[ ] answer = new IntNode[2];

      if (source == null)
         return answer;

      copyHead = new IntNode(source.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;

      while (source.link != null)
      {
         source = source.link;
         copyTail.addAfter(source.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      answer[0] = copyHead;
      answer[1] = copyTail;
      return answer;
   }


   public static int listLength(IntNode head) {
      IntNode cursor;
      int answer;

      answer = 0;
      for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
         answer++;

      return answer;
   }


   public static IntNode[ ] listPart(IntNode start, IntNode end) {
      IntNode copyHead;
      IntNode copyTail;
      IntNode cursor;
      IntNode[ ] answer = new IntNode[2];

      copyHead = new IntNode(start.data, null);
      copyTail = copyHead;
      cursor = start;

      while (cursor != end)
      {
         cursor = cursor.link;
         if (cursor == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("end node was not found on the list");
         copyTail.addAfter(cursor.data);
         copyTail = copyTail.link;
      }

      answer[0] = copyHead;
      answer[1] = copyTail;
      return answer;
   }        


   public static IntNode listPosition(IntNode head, int position) {
      IntNode cursor;
      int i;

      if (position <= 0)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("position is not positive");

      cursor = head;
      for (i = 1; (i < position) && (cursor != null); i++)
         cursor = cursor.link;

      return cursor;
   }


   public static IntNode listSearch(IntNode head, int target) {
      IntNode cursor;

      for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
         if (target == cursor.data)
            return cursor;

      return null;
   }


   public void removeNodeAfter( ) {
      link = link.link;
   }          


   public void setData(int newData)   
   {
      data = newData;
   }                                                               


   public void setLink(IntNode newLink) {
      link = newLink;
   }
}
```

---

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String args[])   {
        IntNode head = new IntNode(-1, null);
        Sorter sorter = new Sorter();

        head.addAfter(2);
        head.addAfter(4);
        head.addAfter(5);
        head.addAfter(3);
        head.addAfter(6);
        head.addAfter(9);
        head.addAfter(8);
        head.addAfter(10);

        head.setLink(sorter.nodeSort(head));

        for (IntNode i = head; i != null; i = i.getLink()) {
            System.out.println(i.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the null pointer exception trace.

Comment: Is the `addAfter` correct? It seems to just delete the previous `head.link` and replace it with the new `IntNode`.

Comment: Say the node has a link that points to null. When addAfter is called, it makes the link point to the new node that contains item and tells it to point to the place the node used to point to point to, in our case-null.

Comment: I tried to throw null pointer exception, it didn't work. I think I am referencing outside the bounds of the linked list, but I don't know where it happened.

Comment: @zgangwer20 Shouldn't it be `while(currNode.link != null) { currNode = currNode.link; }` before setting the link then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your sorting method. I provide you an implementation based on your data structure. Hope this helps...

```
public void selectionSort(IntNode head) {
    for (IntNode node1 = head; node1 != null; node1 = node1.getLink()) {
        IntNode min = node1;
        for (IntNode node2 = node1; node2 != null; node2 = node2.getLink()) {
            if (min.getData() > node2.getData()) {
                min = node2;
            }

        }
        IntNode temp = new IntNode(node1.getData(), null);
        node1.setData(min.getData());
        min.setData(temp.getData());
    }
}
```

And you don't need to return the head node, so your main method can look like the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    IntNode head = new IntNode(-1, null);
    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();

    head.addAfter(4);
    head.addAfter(5);
    head.addAfter(2);
    head.addAfter(3);
    head.addAfter(6);
    head.addAfter(9);
    head.addAfter(8);
    head.addAfter(10);

    sorter.selectionSort(head);

    for (IntNode i = head; i != null; i = i.getLink()) {
        System.out.println(i.getData());
    }
}
```